# What is the intuitive explanation for why a system can be stable with a negative gain margin?

Tags: electrical-engineering, control-engineering, control-theory, signal-processing

Beyond the math which shows that a gain of -1 and a phase of -180 (G(s)=-1)causes instability when the open-loop TF is taken to closed loop, the way I've always justified the instability of G(s)=-1 intuitively is by thinking of the behavior on a standard sine wave. Because of the negative feedback and negative gain, it will effectively multiply the sine wave input infinitely.

If G(s)=-2, however, the closed loop system somehow becomes stable, despite the same intuitive logic seeming to hold. The below image should help describe why intuitively, it seems like a closed loop system with G(s)=-2 should be unstable.

[image: intuitive description]

Again, I understand things from a mathematical perspective, but where is my intuition failing me?

Edit: The transfer function I plotted in Matlab which shows stability is as follows:

```
test_tf = tf([-2],[1]);
test_tf = feedback(test_tf,1);
t = linspace(0,100,1000);
u = sin(t);
y = lsim(test_tf, u, t);
plot(t,y)
```

Comment: I doubt that this observation holds for all systems. Please provide an example of a system by editing the question. Other than the hand drawn figures, could you get the stable response by doing a simulation?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your comment. And yes, you can get a stable response for G(s)=-2 with Matlab, but I'm trying to understand the intuitive reason WHY the system is stable, despite being the same scenario as G(s)=-1 just with even more amplification. @AJN

Comment: It requires the system which you simulated in matlab to be posted in the question using the [edit] option below the question.

Comment: Added the Matlab code to the question

Comment: This system appears to be not-strictly-proper. Is the concept of gain margin applicable to this system?

Comment: I'm not sure 'stable' is the correct description. Perhaps Matlab gives an indeterminate result for indeterminate conditions?